# How to create and put div at vacant place of browser in the form of circle without colliding with each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 1 browser screen where i want to **display list of user in circle** along with their **name and image** like below:

[image]

My code:

```js
 var $container = $("#container");
                var htmlString = "";
                var data1 = [{
                    "Name": "ABC",
                    "Url": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/5f/fa/06/5ffa0655ce8781a50113580f29828f53.jpg"
                }, {
                    "Name": "PQR",
                    "Url": "http://worldofarts.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/3-flower-drawings-rose.jpg"
                }, {
                    "Name": "PQR",
                    "Url": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e8/cf/c8/e8cfc83e4385505cf45a4099ee4073cb.jpg"
                }];

                $.each(data1, function (index, value) {
                    htmlString += '<div class="newDiv" id=' + index + '>' + value.Name + '</div>' + '<br>';
                });
                $container.append(htmlString);
```

```css
 <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            display: block;
            width: 1500px;
            height: 600px;
            background: #ccc;
        }

        body {
            background-color: ivory;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

     

        .newDiv {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            min-width: 50px;
            min-height: 50px;
            background: #e00;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .bouncer {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>  
<div id="container">
    </div>
```

Here I would be making ajax request every few seconds which will fetch data from my database and put new users in the form of circle like shown 
in above image without refreshing page.

But here problem is, how do I find vacant place on my screen and put that circle and my circle as colliding like if you run my code and see?

Comment: consider using the concept of flexbox in css

Comment: @Learning did you want to put them in random places?

Comment: @Sachin:Can you please post a link or something because i dont know what is flexbox

Comment: @lerouche:Yes random place but vacant place with some distance and they should not collide with eachother

Comment: (This is far too broad, as it is asking for a circle placement algorithm, with no attempt.)

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox , you could arrange your user divs in any way you like. See my codepen http://codepen.io/keephacking/pen/VaGyEo:

```
display:flex; //for more see my codepen
```

> Not clear about the vacant spaces you mentioned . I hope you can do that with flexbox concept.

For more about flexbox see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: but what if i add so many users then will every div will adjust accordingly without colliding with each other?

Comment: yep it will arrange accordingly..you can check that in my codepen , try please.

Comment: Yup awesome.Simply awesome and i was searching for code and trying with logic like a fool instead of this simple one.Superb.But there is one problem like if i add so many users then it goes out of containers div.can you please check it

Comment: remove `height:100%`

Comment: Yeah now it worked perfectly but how to put image inside circleas because i want image inside circle and name in bottom as you can see in my image??

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var $container = $("#container");
                var htmlString = "";
                var margin = 0;
                var data1 = [{
                    "Name": "ABC",
                    "Url": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/5f/fa/06/5ffa0655ce8781a50113580f29828f53.jpg"
                }, {
                    "Name": "PQR",
                    "Url": "http://worldofarts.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/3-flower-drawings-rose.jpg"
                }, {
                    "Name": "PQR",
                    "Url": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e8/cf/c8/e8cfc83e4385505cf45a4099ee4073cb.jpg"
                }];

                $.each(data1, function (index, value) {
                    htmlString += '<div style="margin-left: '+ margin +'px;" class="newDiv" id=' + index + '>' + value.Name + '</div>' + '<br>';
                   margin += 100;
                });
                $container.append(htmlString);
```

```css
 <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            display: block;
            width: 1500px;
            height: 600px;
            background: #ccc;
        }

        body {
            background-color: ivory;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

     

        .newDiv {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            min-width: 50px;
            min-height: 50px;
            background: #e00;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 50%;
            z-index: 2;
            display:flex;
            clear:both;
        }

        .bouncer {
            position: relative;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>  
<div id="container">
    </div>
```

Comment: try this, does this work for you?

Comment: for the position of the images you can use this

Comment: i have check your code but giving inappropriate output when taking lots of data.they are are dispalying diagonally

Comment: Dont use margin as 1 user suggested this logic:If the distance between the centers of two circles is smaller than the combined radius of both circles, they collide or overlap. The distance between two points is calculated by retrieving the square root of the sum of squares of the individual axis.Now you could just randomly get any coordinate on your plane, check for collision, get new coordinate if required

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Learnin! :)